# Почему при большом количестве radiobuttons пропадают данные из массива POST()?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, yii, post

Есть представление index которое создает форму выбирая данные из таблицы news (по ID), вот фрагмент кода формы, которая отправляет данные:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'action' => Url::toRoute(['default/edit']),
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'thisday-content',
                'data' => ['pjax' => true]
            ],
              'id' => 'senderForm',
]);
?>
//кнопка для сбрасывания значения с формы
<?= Html::resetButton('Сбросить', ['class' => 'btn-default btn', 'name'=> 
'cansel-button']); ?>  
 //кнопка отправки формы в контроллер
<?= Html::submitButton('Далее', ['class' => 'btn-default btn', 'name'=> 
'resume-button']); ?>
<div class="thisday-container">
    <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper">
        <div class="control-group"> 
        <?php foreach ($news as $newsItem => $item):?>
        <?php foreach ($item as $indexItem => $ItemArticle): ?>
            <?php if ($year != $ItemArticle->cdate_int) { echo '</div><div 
class="control-group">'; $year = $ItemArticle->cdate_int; }?>
              <h3 class="group-header"><?= $newsItem ?></h3>
                    <?=
//настройки для радио кнопки в форме. в id кнопки пишется id новости, а в name приходит следующее News2017, News2016 и т.д 
                    $form->field($ItemArticle, 
                        'id[' . $ItemArticle->id . ']')->radio([
                        'name' => 'News['.$ItemArticle->cdate_int.']',
                        'value' => $ItemArticle->id,
//Текст новости
                        'label' => Html::encode($ItemArticle->name)
                        . Html::tag('div', '', ['class' => 
'control__indicator'])
 //условие на выборку новостей с рейтингом
                        . Html::tag('span', empty($ItemArticle->rating) ? 0 
: $ItemArticle->rating->rate, ['class' => 'control-views-count']),
                        'labelOptions' => [
                            'encode' => false,
                            'class' => 'control control--radio',
                        ],
                    ]);
          ?> 
          <?php endforeach; ?>  
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Соответственно, контроллер ловит эту форму и делает там вот так

```
public function actionEdit() {
    $model = new ThisDay;
    $choosedNews = Yii::$app->request->post('News');
    return $this->render('edit', ['model' => $model, 'choosedNews' => 
$choosedNews]);
}
```

В результате, при благоприятном исходе я получаю массив вида

```
array(2) { [2016]=> string(6) "514660" [2017]=> string(6) "616127" }
```

тут 2016, 2017 - это год новости, а 514660 - id новости.

Такой вариант срабатывает если у меня форма как на рисунке ниже (т.е если новостей за указанную в выборе дату и месяц было по одной в каждом году)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если у меня форма возвращается следующего вида (т.е за указанную при выборе дату и время есть много новостей в 2016, 2017 и т.д)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То я получаю массив вида `array(2) { [2017]=> string(1) "0" [2016]=> string(1) "0" }`

Почему данных нет? Вроде все тоже самое...

P.S отладчик мне вежливо сообщил, что после отправки формы от отдает мне данные следующего вида..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е ID новостей среди прочей пустоты есть! Вот только все равно получаю пустой массив почему то.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но если попробовать задать имя элемента как массив `'name' => 'News['.$ItemArticle->cdate_int.'][]',`

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов да, это дейсвтительно сработало! Но почему?

Comment: Вы передаете серверу набор данных `News[2017]` это как переменная которая постоянно переписывается новыми значениями. В итоге `php` получает последние значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Евгений Гаврилов предложил правильное исправление, нужно было при настройке полей формы задавать имя как массив

```
$form->field($ItemArticle, 
  'id[' . $ItemArticle->id . ']')->radio([
  'name' => 'News['.$ItemArticle->cdate_int.'][]',
```